# Is there any way to see how apps write their location frameworks?

Tags: geolocation, app-store

I'd like to compile a list of apps that use location services well (i.e. persistent GPS, high resolution accuracy, etc). Is there any transparency into the way public apps in the app store are written?

Thank you!